# Why this code does not show three legend lines?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, legending, code-review

My code shows empty legend lines. What should I do to show the graph with  three legend lines?

```
eq1 = A1*F'''[\[Eta]] + A2*(F''[\[Eta]] + (F'[\[Eta]])^2) - 
  A1*F'[\[Eta]] - A2*Fr*(F'[\[Eta]])^2 + S2*Exp[-S1 \[Eta]] == 0;
eq2 = Knf*\[Theta]''[\[Eta]] + A1*Pr*F[\[Eta]] \[Theta]'[\[Eta]] +    
  Pr*Nt (\[Theta]'[\[Eta]])^2 +    
  Nb*Pr*\[Theta]'[\[Eta]]*\[CurlyPhi][\[Eta]] == 0;
eq3 = \[CurlyPhi]''[\[Eta]] - Sc*F[\[Eta]]*\[CurlyPhi]'[\[Eta]] +
  Nt/Nb \[Theta]''[\[Eta]] - K1*\[CurlyPhi][\[Eta]] == 0;
bcs1 = {F[0] == S, F'[0] == 0, F'[2] == 1};
bcs2 = {\[Theta]'[0] == -0, \[Theta][2] == 0};
bcs3 = {\[CurlyPhi]'[0] == -1, \[CurlyPhi][2] == 0};
A1 = 1/(1 - \[CurlyPhi]1)^2.5;
A2 = ((1 - \[CurlyPhi]1) + \[CurlyPhi]1*\[Rho]s*Cs/\[Rho]b*Cb);

b1 = Block[{\[CurlyPhi]1 = 0.4, \[Rho]s = 5200, \[Rho]s = 4250, 
    Cs = 670, \[Rho]b = 890, \[Rho]b = 670, Cb = 686.2, k1 = 6, 
    knf = 0.126, Pr = 1.0, Sc = 0.5, S1 = 1.2, 
    S2 = 0.1, \[Lambda] = 0.1, Nt = 0.5, Nb = 0.3, S = 0.2, K1 = 0.8, 
    Fr = 1.3},
      First[NDSolve[{eqn1, eqn2, eqn3, bcs1, bcs2, bcs3}, {F[\[Eta]], 
      F'[\[Eta]], \[Theta][\[Eta]], \[Theta]'[\[Eta]], \ \[Phi][\[Eta]], \[Phi]'[\[Eta]]}, {\[Eta], 0, 4}, 
      Method -> Shooting]]];
b2 = Block[{\[CurlyPhi]1 = 0.4, \[Rho]s = 5200, \[Rho]s = 4250, 
    Cs = 670, \[Rho]b = 890, \[Rho]b = 670, Cb = 686.2, k1 = 6, 
    knf = 0.126, Pr = 1.0, Sc = 0.5, , S1 = 1.2, 
    S2 = 0.1, \[Lambda] = 0.1, Nt = 0.5, Nb = 0.3, S = 0.2, K1 = 0.8, 
    Fr = 1.3},
      First[NDSolve[{eqn1, eqn2, eqn3, bcs1, bcs2, bcs3}, {F[\[Eta]], 
      F'[\[Eta]], \[Theta][\[Eta]], \[Theta]'[\[Eta]], \ \[Phi][\[Eta]], \[Phi]'[\[Eta]]}, {\[Eta], 0, 4}, 
      Method -> Shooting]]];
b3 = Block[{\[CurlyPhi]1 = 0.4, \[Rho]s = 5200, \[Rho]s = 4250, 
    Cs = 670, \[Rho]b = 890, \[Rho]b = 670, Cb = 686.2, k1 = 6, 
    knf = 0.126, Pr = 1.0, Sc = 0.5, S1 = 1.2, 
    S2 = 0.1, \[Lambda] = 0.1, Nt = 0.5, Nb = 0.3, S = 0.2, K1 = 0.8, 
    Fr = 1.3},
      First[NDSolve[{eqn1, eqn2, eqn3, bcs1, bcs2, bcs3}, {F[\[Eta]], 
      F'[\[Eta]], \[Theta][\[Eta]], \[Theta]'[\[Eta]], \ \[Phi][\[Eta]], \[Phi]'[\[Eta]]}, {\[Eta], 0, 4}, 
      Method -> Shooting]]];

Needs["PlotLegends`"]

Plot[Evaluate[{F'[\[Eta]] /. b1, F'[\[Eta]] /. b2,
    F'[\[Eta]] /. b3}], {\[Eta], 0, 4}, PlotRange -> All,
    PlotStyle -> {{Dashing[{solid}], Black}, {Dashing[{solid}], 
    Red}, {Dashing[{solid}], Blue}, {Dashing[{solid}], 
    Green}, {Dashing[{0.01}], Black}, {Dashing[{0.02}], 
    Red}, {Dashing[{0.03}], Blue}, {Dashing[{0.04}], Green}},
    PlotLegend -> {"\[Lambda] = 0.1", "\[Lambda]= 0.2",
      "\[Lambda] = 0.3"}, LegendSize -> {0.4, 0.45},
    LegendPosition -> {-0.01, 0.1}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
    LegendShadow -> False, Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
    FrameLabel -> {Style["\[Eta]", Italic, Black],
    Style["F'(\[Eta])", Italic, Black]}]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Error: There a double definitions of $\rho s$ in Block

Comment: PLease copy your input from here and try it in MMA and make it run.